# Jetpack Compose Coil cache and load

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Load photos from album and cache to memory or disk, when loading from memory or disk.

Below is loading photos from album：

```kotlin
        val model = ImageRequest
                .Builder(current)
                .data(asset.path)
                .crossfade(true)
                .build()

        AsyncImage(model = model,
                contentDescription = "image")
```

How to cache, and how to load from, not over network.

The official documentation is really incomprehensible, various simplifications.